# Can we find an element using text present on a page in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I am writing Selenium webdriver code using c#. Can we find an element using text present on a page like I wanted to assert that on button click, this text from a paragraph is present on the next page.

Thanks

Comment: Would it not make more sense to find the element that the text is usually in and "assert" on that element's text as opposed to "just find this text *somewhere* on this page"? What if the text is shown but on the right hand side instead of the left hand side and the user actually couldn't see the error? Your test would pass but the page is broken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible you can try some thing like this

```
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Text - CHOLERA UNS')]")).click()
```

Comment: Sravan's answer is correct. +1 for that. Just one suggestion, instead of //a use more specific xpath like for example //div/span/a . That will perform better.

Comment: css selectors are faster.